# Javascript function in html body, wont work

Tags: javascript, html

In my document I have an onLoad function given like here in this example:

```
<body onLoad="display()">
```

In addition I added a function at the end of the document which changes some CSS properties:

```
<script>
window.onload = foo(), bar();
</script>
```

Somehow the whole thing doesn't work! I tried to add all functions at the end of the document but I don't get it, somehow they don't trigger!

Comment: `window.onload = foo(), bar();` calls the functions `foo` and `bar` and assigns the return value of `bar` to `window.onload`. I recommend to to learn how to debug JavaScript code: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: have you looked in developer tools / javascript console to see what error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will invoke the functions, but it doesn't assign anything useful to `window.onload` unless your last function happens to return a function.

You need to assign a function to `window.onload` that will invoke your functions when the `window` is ready.

```
window.onload = function() {
    foo();
    bar();
};
```

Plus, since you're putting the script at the bottom, you probably don't need the `window.onload`.

```
    <script>
        foo(); bar();
    </script>
</body>
```

---

You should also be aware that assigning directly to `window.onload` will overwrite the script assigned in the `<body onLoad=...>`, so you shouldn't do both. Currently, the return value of `bar();` is wiping out the function that invokes `display();`.

Getting rid of the `window.onload` assignment will fix that.

Comment: I think you pointed out an important problem but didn't focus on it enough. The fact that `window.onload` overwrites the `<body onload="">`, and that the value assigned to `window.onload` is probably `undefined` (the returned value of calling `bar`. Also, depending on what they actually mean, the OP said the script is at the bottom of the `<body>`: "In addition I added a function at the end of the document"

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I think you're right. Looking at the question again, the new script seems to be at the bottom, so it is the overwrite that is likely the culprit.

Comment: But at the same time, since `foo` and `bar` are called, **and** the document is ready (since the script is at the bottom), wouldn't you think the code would work? I mean, the `onLoad="display()"` won't because it's overwritten, but I would think that no matter what `foo` and `bar` do, those will work. But obviously, `display()` won't ever be run. The OP doesn't make it clear what the "doesn't work" means...

Comment: @Ian: Yes, `foo` and `bar` should work unless they rely on resources being fully loaded. The question could certainly use some clarity.

Comment: Why would `window.onload` *overwrite* the `load` event handler of the `body` element? Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @FelixKling: Because the `<body>` element will be processed before the enclosed `<script>`, and `<body onload=` is a means of assigning a handler to `window.onload`. So its handler is assigned first, and then the script runs. Because a `window.onload` event won't happen until all resources are loaded *(including scripts)*, the handler will be overwritten before it has a chance to run.

Comment: I don't know why, but I thought `load` on `body` would be different than `window.onload`. But I tested it and you are correct. And now I think I'm remembering to have read this somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian: You cannot put `body` tags in jsFiddle (check the frame source). Maybe the browser corrects it, but I don't know how. I used JSBin instead and it's how the system said.

Comment: @FelixKling Haha that's weird, I'm the same way. I would think they'd be different but I also remember reading about this.

Comment: @FelixKling Well it worked. Inspect the target iframe and look at the contents. The `<body>` element has an `onload` event. And if you took out the `window.onload` part, it would alert "body onload"

Comment: @FelixKling: You mean you thought `<body onload=` would actually do what it implies? What were you thinking! ;-)

Comment: @Ian: Oh ok... it still creates malformed HTML though.

Comment: @thesystem: I'm an optimist :D

Comment: @FelixKling Why is it malformed? The DOM looks right in Firebug. I have a feeling jsFiddle looks to see if a `<body>` is in the HTML area, and if so, uses that instead of the default. Maybe I'm misunderstanding things though...

Comment: @FelixKling I think I see what you're saying. Firebug won't show duplicate `<body>` elements, so the browser/Firebug will "correct" it visually. I'm wondering if jsFiddle corrects it before sending it to the iframe though

Comment: @Ian: if you view the HTML source for the rendered pane: http://fiddle.jshell.net/MyPYc/show/ you'll see that the source has `<body><body onload="myFunc();">...</body></body>`. I also wondered if jsFiddle would detect it, but apparently not.

Comment: @FelixKling Ahh yes, didn't think of visiting that URL. So that's interesting. Maybe this is a better proof: http://jsfiddle.net/MyPYc/1/ . I (never) misuse the HTML area (like I see people do on SO plenty), so I assumed it just figured it out for us.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work, as long as `display()` is defined function with no errors.

In the second case, when assigning event handlers via DOM, you need to pass either a function reference (i.e. instead of `foo()` just `foo`) or wrap it in an anonymous function like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
  foo();
}
```

Comment: Technically, calling `foo` or `bar` (in the OP's code) could be returning a function, therefore setting `window.onload` just fine. I doubt it is, but still :)

Comment: That's correct with the addition that in that case the assigned function _call_ should return a function _reference_.

Comment: Well yeah, I meant a function _reference_...what else could it be?