# onload runs unexpected code

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm writing a javascript snippet that will validate the signup form fields.
for some reason, the onsubmit function, is also called when the page loads.

window.onload = function validate_signup_form() {

```
var form_element = document.getElementById("signup_form");
var onload_values = document.forms["signup_form"];
var test = onload_values.elements[0].value;
var required_fields = new Array();

document.getElementById("signup_form").onsubmit = check_values();

function check_values() 
{
    var current_values = document.forms["signup_form"];
    for (x in current_values) 
    {
        if (current_values[x].value == onload_values[x].value) 
        {
            // Error: The form values match the initial ones
            return false;
        } 
        elseif (current_values[x].value.toLowerCase() == onload_values[x].value.toLowerCase()) 
        {
            // Error: The form values match the initial ones
            return false;           
        }
        elseif (current_values[x].value.toUpperCase() == onload_values[x].value.toUpperCase()) 
        {
            // Error: The form values match the initial ones
            return false;           
        }
    }
};
};
```

Shouldn't check_values(); run only on submit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the onsubmit property to the value *returned* by check_values(); Change to the following:

```
document.getElementById("signup_form").onsubmit = check_values;
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess i missed that, on the quick js tutorial I was reading.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985047/javascript-function-in-html-body-wont-work) asked not long ago.

You are assigning the *return value* of the `chekc_values` to `onsubmit` and not the function itself. It should be `onsubmit = check_values;`.

`check_values` is executed at the time of assignment only not when the event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line you are calling `check_values` and setting signup_form's `onsubmit` to whatever the function returns.

```
document.getElementById("signup_form").onsubmit = check_values();
```

Remove the brackets if you want to set the function itself.